# How to configure transient fields with Korma

Tags: mysql, clojure, korma

I am using Clojure with [korma](http://sqlkorma.com/) to store Clojure maps in a Mysql database, e.g storing maps with this structure:

```
(defentity users
  (table :user)
  (entity-fields :email 
                 :password 
                 :name))
```

In a table with four columns `id` (implicitly defined), `email`, `password` and `name`.

So, when I call this piece of code everything works fine:

```
(insert users (values {:email "john@example.com"
                       :password "____hashed_passw___"
                       :name "J"}))
```

The problem I have is that my maps may contain some keys which do not have their corresponding columns in the database (and I do not want to persist these values). For example:

```
(insert users (values {:email "john@example.com"
                       :password "____hashed_passw___"
                       :name "J"
                       :something "else"}))
```

Would throw an error `MySQLSyntaxErrorException Unknown column 'something' in 'field list'`.

Ideally, what I would like to know is if there is an option somewhere in Korma to ignore the extra keys present in the map. The problem *could* be solved by `dissoc`-ing all of them on save, but I'd prefer to find out if there is a built in way to do it before I do that (or any other better idea).

Comment: I don't think there is anything as such inbuilt in Korma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to remove extra key/value pairs from the map. Arguably Korma could be made to remove them, based on defentities.

I suggest you either bring it up on https://github.com/korma/Korma as a feature request or look into adding it yourself. Chris Granger, the maintainer, is easy to talk to and would probably consider your idea.